# How to make clickable around link if its active?

Tags: html, css

On my navigation bar, when i hover with my mouse, i have to click directly on text, but i want to be arond it because when i come close to text, the hover background appear, but its not clickable until i put the mouse on text, i hope you understand me. Here is the code:

```
echo '
    <nav>
    <ul>';

    foreach($variables['menu_buttons'] as $act => $button)
    {
        $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $class = (GetCurrentPageAdress() == $button['href']) ? 'active' : '';
        echo '<li id="button_'.$act.'"><a class="'.$class.'" href="'.$button['href'].'">'.$button['title'].'</a></li>'; 
    }

echo '
    </ul>
    <div class="handle"></div>
    </nav>';
```

This is the line: `echo '<li id="button_'.$act.'"><a class="'.$class.'" href="'.$button['href'].'">'.$button['title'].'</a></li>';`

I can make it clickable but then i cant make it to stay active...

Comment: use `li:hover > a` in your css to set the background etc..

Comment: @NikosM. But, its already set. The background and active link is working, but i cant click around link. Take a look at this image, the cursor is not "pointer" its normal until i hover the text. [link](http://i.imgur.com/5P6EWzS.png)

Comment: then make your `a` element take all space of the wrapper `li` element, e.g have `padding:0` on `li` and make it wrap tightly around `a` and add all the other `li` styles (e.g `padding`) in the `a` element

Comment: @NikosM. Yeah, i know that and its working, now i can click around text and its all ok but now i can not make it active, i can not make it call "active" when its inside `a`

Comment: add a jsfiddle with an example to understand better

Comment: Lets make it simple. I just need help to make my navigation bar when i click Home page, to stay active. Understand? Thats the problem. With the code i gave you, its working, but the thing with background clickable link is not working. When i fix that second problem, the first one is working, but when i fix the first one, the second is not working. I rly dont know how to put that part of the script into jsfiddle because it will not read properly.

Comment: add a jsfiddle to showcase your css html etc.. so a concrete answer can be given.  Your code posted and your question as is do not explain much, understand?

Comment: in the jsfiddle just put the html code and any css code (not the php code). Use the php code to get the final html and use that in the fiddle, simple

Comment: Is it possible that you add your CSS snippet for these navigation bar ? (No need to put the whole stylesheet, only those that got used with your navigation bar). By this, we can see directly where the problem is, and give you a solution. I know what you want, but the solution depends of how you have styled your navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

in order to make the whole background of the link clickable you should style the link with css like so:

```
a{
  display:block;
  width: the_widh_you_want;
  height:the_height_you_want
}
```

and now you have a link which the whole background is clickable too.

Answer (score 0):

I you should set the `<a>` background to transparent (you can use any color) as such

```
a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This makes its internal area clickable (not just the text)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not clear how your navigation bar got styled but here below is an example of how i should do this.

```
nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* notice the display and the padding */
nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

/* displays hover effect */
nav li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Here below is the whole snippet with an example. Please ignore the HTML and JavaScript part, these are used to give you a working example.

Just run it (click on that big blue "Run code snippet" and try to click on the elements. As you can see, you don't have to click the text anymore.

```js
// IGNORE THIS: not required, just to proof that the link got clicked.
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('lnk');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('hai').innerHTML = "clicked " + event.target.innerHTML;
  })
}
```

```css
nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

nav li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="button_1"><a class="lnk" href="#1">link1</a></li>
    <li id="button_2"><a class="lnk" href="#2">link2</a></li>
    <li id="button_3"><a class="lnk" href="#3">link3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="handle"></div>
</nav>
<p id="hai"></p>
```